# How confirm Message Box with OK or Cancel option in ASP .NET MVC 5 (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I work with ASP .NET MVC 5 . I want when I click exit button in View show Message Box that Returns  OK or Cancel . How can I do this ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much - @ThinLe

Comment: I want check if my Function Returns "You pressed OK!"   go to for example Login View , else if Returns  "You pressed Cancel!" go to Index View . How can I do this ? Are you help me  ? I don't know how write HTML code for this condition .- @ThinLe

Comment: Use can use: window.open("your link", "_self") to open page in current page